# Using localStorage to disable a button in Meteor and Sugar JS

Tags: meteor

When someone clicks this button it disables for 10 seconds

```
Template.hello.events({
  'click input.hack': function () {
    var oneMinute = ((10).secondsAfter(this.Date));
    Session.set('endingDate',oneMinute); 
    Meteor.call('hackclick');
  },
});
```

This is the code that disables the button based on the time.

```
Template.hello.helpers({
  'disabledBtn': function(){
      var eDate = Session.get('endingDate'); 
      var nDate = ((1).secondsBefore(this.Date));
      if( nDate <= eDate){
      return "disabled"
      } else {
      return
      }
  } 
});
```

But doing it this way means you can refresh the browser and the disable goes away.

I tried using localStorage but it would not work.

```
'click input.hack': function () {
  var oneMinute = ((10).secondsAfter(this.Date));
  localStorage.setItem('timerend', oneMinute);
  Meteor.call('hackclick');
},

'disabledBtn': function(){
    var eDate = localStorage.getItem('timerend');
    var nDate = ((1).secondsBefore(this.Date));
    if( nDate <= eDate){
    return "disabled"
    } else {
    return
    }
}
```

I even tried to store the now time in a localStorage to see if that worked. But nope.

Any ideas why? Should I just try storing it in the DB? I thought localStorage would be more scale-able.

Comment: what's the value being return by 'timerend'?

Comment: It is storing the date like this. Mon Jun 08 2015 21:21:12 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` stores values as strings. You need to parse the saved item into a `Date` once you retrieve it.

```
var eDate = localStorage.getItem('timerend');
eDate = new Date(eDate); // do it something like this
```

You can see this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/L98fgmnd/)** as an example.